# ¿Cómo puedo guardar en local el pdf que he generado con html2pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, nodejs, html2pdf

estoy generando un pdf con html2pdf, y he logrado generar el pdf, pero ahora necesito mandar este pdf a mi servidor en node o guardarlo directamente en una carpeta en mi servidor, ahora el pdf se descarga en la ruta que indica el cliente, pero yo necesito tener una copia en mi servidor, he probado con el parámetro output pero no he logrado nada, este es mi código actual:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        // Escuchamos el click del botón
        const $boton = document.querySelector("#btnCrearPdf");
        $boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const $elementoParaConvertir = document.body; // <-- Aquí puedes elegir cualquier elemento del DOM
            html2pdf()
                .set({
                    margin: 1,
                    filename: 'documento.pdf',
                    image: {
                        type: 'jpeg',
                        quality: 0.98
                    },
                    html2canvas: {
                        scale: 3, // A mayor escala, mejores gráficos, pero más peso
                        letterRendering: true,
                    },
                    jsPDF: {
                        unit: "in",
                        format: "a3",
                        orientation: 'portrait' // landscape o portrait
                    }
                })
                .from($elementoParaConvertir)
                .save()
                .output('./123123123.pdf', 'f')
                .then(pdfResult => {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/guardarPdf",
                        data: `pdf=${pdfResult}`,
                        success: function (res) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
        });
    });
```

Pero no logro encontrar la manera de enviar el pdf al servidor o guardarlo directamente desde el frontend, al mandarlo al servidor en node con la función ajax, node me lanza el siguiente error:

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer para guardar el pdf que se me genera en mi servidor? Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿No sería más lógico crear el PDF en el servidor y que el usuario lo descargara?

Comment: ¿Puedes cambiar la configuración el servidor para incrementar la cantidad de datos que acepta?

Comment: he probado a cambiar la cantidad de datos pero me sigue dando el mismo fallo, no existe alguna forma desde el javascript del frontend, de guardarlo en una carpeta? o como podría hacer para generar el pdf desde el propio servidor @PabloLozano?? Muchas gracias

Comment: a parte he de decir, que lo que estoy haciendo es generar un pdf con datos dinámicos sacados de mi base de datos, por tanto yo tengo una plantilla en blanco que sería el html, y la lleno con los datos antes de generar el pdf, no es solamente generar un pdf de un archivo html que tengo en mi proyecto

Answer (score 0):

```
.output('./123123123.pdf', 'f')
```

en esta parte del codigo debes cmabiarlo por la ruta local `.output(__DIR__ . 'doc.pdf', 'F')` por ejemplo o `.output(C:\miruta\doc.pdf, 'F');`

el chiste es que el origen de la ruta sea local, no acepta url dinamica.